# Calling a matlab function with python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I have a python code which runs a matlab function sussum(a,nx,ny) in the background with subprocess.Popen. I am not able to get it working. Because I'm unable to pass the input arguments to matlab correctly. Here is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
 import matlab.engine
 import scipy.io as sio
 import numpy as np
 import subprocess as sb
 nproc = 5
 input = sio.loadmat('sus_py.mat')
 totq = input['totq']
 nx,ny = input['nx'],input['ny']
 nq = totq+1
 nx,ny = matlab.int32(nx.tolist()) , matlab.int32(ny.tolist())
 iq = range(1,nq)
 gp = len(iq)/nproc
 list = [iq[j:j+nproc] for j in range(0,len(iq),nproc)]
 for g in range(0,len(list)):
     i = len(list[g])
     p = []
     for n in range(0,i):
         a = matlab.int32(list[g][n])
         fun = '-r "sussum(a,nx,ny); exit" '
         lmb = ['/usr/local/bin/matlab','-nodesktop','-nosplash','-nodisplay','-nojvm',fun]
         p.append(sb.Popen(lmb))
     for q in p:
         q.wait()
```

The python script executes in the command terminal of a cluster network, until it spits out the error message: Undefined function or variable 'a'.

I am sure that the matlab function sussum(a,nx,ny) works fine because I have tested it using Python-Matlab API as matlab.engine.start_matlab().sussum(a,nx,ny) and it gave the desired outputs. Any help in getting the python code running with subprocess.Popen() will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're not passing the values of your variables to the function, you're effectively writing the string "sussum(a,nx,ny)" as a parameter to shell when you call Popen. The same as if you typed your lmb verbatim into the shell, it has no notion of the value of those variables. You'll need to translate them from the numpy matrices into Matlab syntax to pass the values in, rather than the names of the variables, if you want to call the function this way

Comment: @TWReever: You should put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `subprocess.Popen(args)` to create a `Popen` object, you're effectively using it to pass the contents of your `lmb` list list (joined with spaces) to the shell to be executed. In this case, the equivalent of your command would be:

```
/usr/local/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplah -nodisplay -nojvm -r "sussum(a,nx,ny); exit"
```

Obviously, this would cause an error if you ran it directly from the shell, because the MATLAB instance created by this command does not know that the `a`, `nx` and `ny` are variables, and the shell just treats the whole thing a string that it is passing as the argument to the `-r` parameter in this case. If you were running this from the command line, you'd need to replace those symbols with values that mean something when it gets passed in to MATLAB. You could do this either by manually writing the variables in the command itself, or using the appropriate means of variable expansion for the shell you're using.

In the case you're trying, running it through a Python `Popen` object,  you need to substitute the variables into the actual `fun` string. If you were doing this *strictly* in Python, you could do something like

```
# define variables
a = 10
nx = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ny = [10, 20, 30, 40]

# build fun string from above variables
# -r "sussum(10, [1,2,3,4], [10,20,30,40]); exit;
fun = '-r "sussum({}, [{}], [{}]); exit";'.format(a, ','.join(nx), ','.join(ny))
```

Unfortunately, since you're pulling your `a`, `nx` and `ny` values from a `numpy.ndarray` given to you by `scipy.io.loadmat` you've got a little more work ahead of you to extract the values from there and format them into a format acceptable to the `sussum` function.